# Error when using *whatNWISdata* function within *dataRetrieval* package from USGS: All components of query must be named

Tags: r, function, httr, data-retrieval

I am trying to use the *whatNWISdata* function to retrieve all available data for specific USGS sites.

I get the following error after trying to execute the function:

```
siteNo <- "09508300"

dailyDataAvailable <- whatNWISdata(siteNo, service = "dv", parameterCd = "00060", 
                                   statCd = "00003")
```

Yields:

> Error: All components of query must be named

Although I am using the function as recommended in [rdocumentation.org](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dataRetrieval/versions/2.5.3/topics/whatNWISdata) and [cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dataRetrieval/vignettes/dataRetrieval.html#whatnwisdata), I get the same error. My [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) is updated to the latest version and so is my *dataRetrieval* package that this function is part of.

This error was a question that was brought up in 2016 on [github](https://github.com/cscheid/rgithub/issues/60), and they recommended downgrading the [httr](/questions/tagged/httr) package, but the *httr* package has been updated since this question was asked and it seems this issue was resolved in the update.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know this framework, but from the error message, I'd guess that the `siteNo` needs a value, like the other parameters, so `dailyDataAvailable <- whatNWISdata(siteNo=,"09508300", service = "dv",`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for your input @Dragonthoughts!

I emailed the author and apparently they had made some slight edits in the format of the input values, and yes you are correct in that the first argument needed a value as in the other inputs for the function.

For anyone else having this problem, it works when you change the input to be like this: `dailyDataAvailable <- whatNWISdata(siteNumber = "09508300", service = "dv", parameterCd = "00060", statCd = "00003")`